# Lazy Load products in Magento 1.9.4

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

How can a load products by scrolling down the page in Magento 1.9.4

**You can also suggest me any free extension.**

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below extensions for Lazy Load:

https://www.magebees.com/magento-lazy-load-images.html

https://www.mgt-commerce.com/magento-lazy-load-images.html